# Get block programmatically

Tags: 8, blocks

It is possible get parent `entity` `block` by entity `block_content`? I don't know the `block`'s machine name but I have a uuid of `block_content`

Comment: I don’t really understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Kevin sorry. I am from Russia;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [BlockContent::getInstances](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block_content%21src%21Entity%21BlockContent.php/function/BlockContent%3A%3AgetInstances/8.4.x)

```
$blocks = $block_content->getInstances();
```

or the code of this method directly:

```
$blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block')->loadByProperties([
  'plugin' => 'block_content:' . $uuid,
]);
```