# How can I programmatically distinguish if a block is enabled or disabled from block layout?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have 2 custom blocks. I have added both this in regions of block layout. But when i disabled the block from layout. I must identify it from code or api that the particular block is disabled. How to know that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use BlockContent::getInstances to get all blocks placed for this custom block, then check for each block instance if it is enabled with `$block->status()`.

See [Get block programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251432/get-block-programmatically/251447#251447) and [How can we check whether block is enabled or disabled in .theme file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288191/how-can-we-check-whether-block-is-enabled-or-disabled-in-theme-file)